# How does he knows about my request headers?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-headers, http-post

So I found for myself an interesting question, that I cannot answer. Here I have a Controller with method to handle POST request:

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@PostMapping("/signout")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<AuthResponse> logout(@RequestHeader(value = AUTH) String token) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    if (loginningService.logout(token)) {
        headers.remove(AUTH);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new AuthResponse("logged out"), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new AuthResponse("Logout failed"), headers, HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED);
}
```

Here HttpHeader instance created, and then loginningService removes token from DB. And then header "Authorization" is removed from the headers object. So question is, how does it takes headers from my request? Didn't I instantiated an object from scratch?

I assume that it's done automatically, but where I can read about it, so in future I won't face issues like that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just wondering, what does `curl` produce for your POST requests?

Comment: Does the `headers` object contain the `Authorization` header _before_ you remove it? The request `Authorization` header shouldn't be automatically copied to the response headers.

Comment: Nothing is removed. There is no headers to remove in a newly constructed [HttpHeaders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#HttpHeaders--). That code works by chance, since it's returning empty headers anyway. Bad code, nothing "magical" happening.

Comment: Do you also have any request/response interceptors or web filters around?

Comment: @fluffy how would they affect calling `headers.remove(AUTH);` on an empty `headers`? There's nothing that would intercept what's happening between instantiating a local variable, and performing a useless operation.

Comment: @Kayaman Wouldn't they be able to transform the response entity after the controller method is done?

Comment: @Kayaman It depends on how one interprets "he". I did interpret it like the headers are not really removed for whatever reasons and someone ("he") "knows" the header after the POST is done. If the "he" is someone to remove something from an empty map, `headers`, then yes, I didn't get that.

Comment: @Kayaman glad you've figured out a confusing question, even if you weren't wondering whether the given code is an outcome of bad merge by "he" whatoever. Have +1.

Comment: Agree with @Kayaman, I just found code on Github, and tried to understand this developer voodoo. 
So anyone who reads this question, don't do like this, access headers with RequestHeader. Thanks for your answers and time guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no Spring magic here, only bad developer voodoo.

Since `HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();` creates an [empty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#HttpHeaders--) headers, calling `headers.remove(AUTH);` won't do anything as there's nothing to remove.

So no matter what `logout(token)` returns, empty headers will be returned from this method. Since empty headers don't have the AUTH header, this can seem like the code "removes" the AUTH header, but this is just a side effect. The code looks like it's doing something, and by accident the behaviour is almost like it.

If you make `logout()` fail, you'll notice that there's no AUTH header either, even though it's supposed to be removed only on a successful logout.

Maybe you want to inject the full headers in the method?

```
public ResponseEntity<AuthResponse> logout(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
```

Comment: I found this code in GitHub, in order to understand how security can be applied to microservieces and Zuul. Now accessing to HttpHeaders with @RequestHeader.